# ESP8266 - Unable to connect to MQTT Server via SSL (mutual authentication)

Tags: openssl, mqtt, esp8266, freertos, esp-idf

I'm trying to connect to MQTT Server with a self signed CA.
Using the terminal command
`mosquitto_sub -h my.mqttserver.com -p 8883 -t '$SYS/#' -v --cafile cacert.pem --cert client.crt --key client.key`  i'm able to connect but using Arduino or ESP-IDF i'm unable to connect.

The CA verification succeeded but at the moment of client authentication the client refuse the connection. Actually on the server logs nothing is shown so i suppose is a client issue.

Actually, using the ESP-IDF example (https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/tree/master/examples/protocols/mqtt/ssl_mutual_auth) the results are the following.

```
I (318287) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:8084 => handshake

I (318290) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:3510 client state: 0

I (318293) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (318298) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2767 <= flush output

I (318307) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:3510 client state: 1

I (318317) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (318324) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2767 <= flush output

I (318333) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:774 => write client hello

I (318410) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3184 => write handshake message

I (318421) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3343 => write record

I (318462) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (318465) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2774 message length: 364, out_left: 364

I (318477) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2779 ssl->f_send() returned 364 (-0xfffffe94)

I (318481) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2807 <= flush output

I (318488) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3476 <= write record

I (318497) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3320 <= write handshake message

I (318508) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:1106 <= write client hello

I (318517) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:3510 client state: 2

I (318526) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (318534) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2767 <= flush output

I (318543) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:1499 => parse server hello

I (318552) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:4311 => read record

I (318561) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2536 => fetch input

I (318569) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2697 in_left: 0, nb_want: 5

I (318650) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2721 in_left: 0, nb_want: 5

I (318654) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2722 ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 5 (-0xfffffffb)

I (318658) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2742 <= fetch input

I (318669) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2536 => fetch input

I (318678) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2697 in_left: 5, nb_want: 92

I (318687) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2721 in_left: 5, nb_want: 92

I (318695) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2722 ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 87 (-0xffffffa9)

I (318708) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2742 <= fetch input

I (318733) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:4385 <= read record

I (318752) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:1789 server hello, total extension length: 11

I (318757) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:1978 <= parse server hello

I (318760) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:3510 client state: 3

I (318768) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (318777) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2767 <= flush output

I (318786) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:5655 => parse certificate

I (318795) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:4311 => read record

I (318804) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2536 => fetch input

I (318812) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2697 in_left: 0, nb_want: 5

I (318823) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2721 in_left: 0, nb_want: 5

I (318832) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2722 ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 5 (-0xfffffffb)

I (318845) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2742 <= fetch input

I (318855) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2536 => fetch input

I (318862) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2697 in_left: 5, nb_want: 1906

I (318879) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2721 in_left: 5, nb_want: 1906

I (318882) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2722 ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 1901 (-0xfffff893)

I (318895) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2742 <= fetch input

I (319105) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:4385 <= read record

I (319254) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:5863 <= parse certificate

I (319257) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:3510 client state: 4

I (319260) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (319266) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2767 <= flush output

I (319275) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:2336 => parse server key exchange

I (319285) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:4311 => read record

I (319294) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2536 => fetch input

I (319303) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2697 in_left: 0, nb_want: 5

I (319314) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2721 in_left: 0, nb_want: 5

I (319322) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2722 ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 5 (-0xfffffffb)

I (319335) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2742 <= fetch input

I (319346) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2536 => fetch input

I (319359) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2697 in_left: 5, nb_want: 406

I (319363) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2721 in_left: 5, nb_want: 406

I (319372) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2722 ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 401 (-0xfffffe6f)

I (319385) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2742 <= fetch input

I (319437) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:4385 <= read record

I (319489) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:2044 ECDH curve: secp521r1

I (319505) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:2278 Server used SignatureAlgorithm 1

I (319508) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:2279 Server used HashAlgorithm 6

I (319627) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:2664 <= parse server key exchange

I (319630) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:3510 client state: 5

I (319633) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (319640) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2767 <= flush output

I (319649) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:2697 => parse certificate request

I (319660) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:4311 => read record

I (319668) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2536 => fetch input

I (319677) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2697 in_left: 0, nb_want: 5

I (319688) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2721 in_left: 0, nb_want: 5

I (319696) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2722 ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 5 (-0xfffffffb)

I (319709) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2742 <= fetch input

I (319719) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2536 => fetch input

I (319726) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2697 in_left: 5, nb_want: 121

I (319738) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2721 in_left: 5, nb_want: 121

I (319746) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2722 ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 116 (-0xffffff8c)

I (319759) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2742 <= fetch input

I (319783) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:4385 <= read record

I (319790) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:2846 <= parse certificate request

I (319793) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:3510 client state: 6

I (319796) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (319805) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2767 <= flush output

I (319814) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:2856 => parse server hello done

I (319824) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:4311 => read record

I (319832) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2536 => fetch input

I (319841) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2697 in_left: 0, nb_want: 5

I (319854) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2721 in_left: 0, nb_want: 5

I (319860) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2722 ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 5 (-0xfffffffb)

I (319873) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2742 <= fetch input

I (319884) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2536 => fetch input

I (319890) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2697 in_left: 5, nb_want: 9

I (319902) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2721 in_left: 5, nb_want: 9

I (319910) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2722 ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned 4 (-0xfffffffc)

I (319923) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2742 <= fetch input

I (319934) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:4385 <= read record

I (319940) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:2886 <= parse server hello done

I (319950) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:3510 client state: 7

I (319959) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (319967) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2767 <= flush output

I (319976) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:5329 => write certificate

I (320016) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3184 => write handshake message

I (320023) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3343 => write record

I (320121) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (320124) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2774 message length: 899, out_left: 899

I (320134) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2779 ssl->f_send() returned 899 (-0xfffffc7d)

I (320139) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2807 <= flush output

I (320147) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3476 <= write record

I (320156) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3320 <= write handshake message

I (320166) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:5433 <= write certificate

I (320175) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:3510 client state: 8

I (320184) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (320192) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2767 <= flush output

I (320201) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:2898 => write client key exchange

I (323620) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3184 => write handshake message

I (323624) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3343 => write record

I (323642) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2755 => flush output

I (323647) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2774 message length: 143, out_left: 143

I (323652) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:2779 ssl->f_send() returned -80 (-0x0050)

W (323659) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3472 mbedtls_ssl_flush_output() returned -80 (-0x0050)

W (323672) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:3315 ssl_write_record() returned -80 (-0x0050)

W (323684) mbedtls: ssl_cli.c:3168 mbedtls_ssl_write_handshake_msg() returned -80 (-0x0050)

I (323698) mbedtls: ssl_tls.c:8094 <= handshake

E (323706) esp-tls-mbedtls: mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x50
I (323716) esp-tls-mbedtls: Certificate verified.
E (323725) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection
E (323733) TRANS_SSL: Failed to open a new connection
E (323746) MQTT_CLIENT: Error transport connect
I (323750) MQTTS_EXAMPLE: MQTT_EVENT_ERROR
I (323758) MQTTS_EXAMPLE: MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED
```

Here my config

```
#
# Automatically generated file. DO NOT EDIT.
# Espressif IoT Development Framework (ESP-IDF) Project Configuration
#
CONFIG_IDF_TARGET_ESP8266=y
CONFIG_IDF_TARGET="esp8266"

#
# SDK tool configuration
#
CONFIG_SDK_TOOLPREFIX="xtensa-lx106-elf-"
CONFIG_SDK_PYTHON="python"
# CONFIG_SDK_MAKE_WARN_UNDEFINED_VARIABLES is not set
CONFIG_BOOTLOADER_INIT_SPI_FLASH=y
# CONFIG_BOOTLOADER_DISABLE_JTAG_IO is not set
# CONFIG_BOOTLOADER_FAST_BOOT is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_NONE is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_ERROR is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_WARN is not set
CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_INFO=y
# CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_VERBOSE is not set
CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL=3
# CONFIG_BOOTLOADER_APP_TEST is not set
CONFIG_BOOTLOADER_STORE_OFFSET=0x0
CONFIG_BOOTLOADER_FLASH_XMC_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_PORT="/dev/cu.usbserial-1430"
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_BAUD_115200B=y
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_BAUD_230400B is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_BAUD_921600B is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_BAUD_2MB is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_BAUD_OTHER is not set
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_BAUD_OTHER_VAL=115200
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_BAUD=115200
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_COMPRESSED=y
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHMODE_QIO is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHMODE_QOUT is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHMODE_DIO is not set
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHMODE_DOUT=y
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHMODE="dout"
CONFIG_SPI_FLASH_MODE=0x3
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHFREQ_80M is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHFREQ_40M is not set
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHFREQ_26M=y
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHFREQ_20M is not set
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHFREQ="26m"
CONFIG_SPI_FLASH_FREQ=0x1
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHSIZE_1MB is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHSIZE_2MB is not set
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHSIZE_4MB=y
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHSIZE_8MB is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHSIZE_16MB is not set
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_FLASHSIZE="4MB"
CONFIG_SPI_FLASH_SIZE=0x400000
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_BEFORE_RESET=y
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_BEFORE_NORESET is not set
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_BEFORE="default_reset"
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_AFTER_HARD_RESET=y
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_AFTER_SOFT_RESET is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_AFTER_NORESET is not set
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_AFTER="hard_reset"
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_MONITOR_BAUD_9600B is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_MONITOR_BAUD_57600B is not set
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_MONITOR_BAUD_74880B=y
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_MONITOR_BAUD_115200B is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_MONITOR_BAUD_230400B is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_MONITOR_BAUD_921600B is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_MONITOR_BAUD_2MB is not set
# CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_MONITOR_BAUD_OTHER is not set
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_MONITOR_BAUD_OTHER_VAL=74880
CONFIG_ESPTOOLPY_MONITOR_BAUD=74880
CONFIG_PARTITION_TABLE_SINGLE_APP=y
# CONFIG_PARTITION_TABLE_TWO_OTA is not set
# CONFIG_PARTITION_TABLE_CUSTOM is not set
CONFIG_PARTITION_TABLE_CUSTOM_FILENAME="partitions.csv"
CONFIG_PARTITION_TABLE_OFFSET=0x8000
CONFIG_PARTITION_TABLE_FILENAME="partitions_singleapp.csv"
CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_SSID="NATO LAVORATORIO SUPER"
CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_PASSWORD="NatoLavoratorio2023!"
# CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_IPV6 is not set
CONFIG_COMPILER_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL_DEBUG=y
# CONFIG_COMPILER_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL_RELEASE is not set
CONFIG_COMPILER_OPTIMIZATION_ASSERTIONS_ENABLE=y
# CONFIG_COMPILER_OPTIMIZATION_ASSERTIONS_SILENT is not set
# CONFIG_COMPILER_OPTIMIZATION_ASSERTIONS_DISABLE is not set
# CONFIG_COMPILER_CXX_EXCEPTIONS is not set
CONFIG_COMPILER_STACK_CHECK_MODE_NONE=y
# CONFIG_COMPILER_STACK_CHECK_MODE_NORM is not set
# CONFIG_COMPILER_STACK_CHECK_MODE_STRONG is not set
# CONFIG_COMPILER_STACK_CHECK_MODE_ALL is not set
# CONFIG_COMPILER_STACK_CHECK is not set
CONFIG_COMPILER_WARN_WRITE_STRINGS=y
CONFIG_APP_UPDATE_CHECK_APP_SUM=y
# CONFIG_APP_UPDATE_CHECK_APP_HASH is not set
CONFIG_APP_COMPILE_TIME_DATE=y
# CONFIG_APP_EXCLUDE_PROJECT_VER_VAR is not set
# CONFIG_APP_EXCLUDE_PROJECT_NAME_VAR is not set
# CONFIG_APP_PROJECT_VER_FROM_CONFIG is not set
# CONFIG_ENABLE_COAP is not set
CONFIG_ESP_TLS_USING_MBEDTLS=y
# CONFIG_ESP_TLS_USING_WOLFSSL is not set
# CONFIG_ESP_TLS_SERVER is not set
# CONFIG_ESP_TLS_PSK_VERIFICATION is not set
# CONFIG_ESP_TLS_INSECURE is not set
# CONFIG_ESP_WOLFSSL_INTERNAL is not set
# CONFIG_WOLFSSL_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_ESP8266_NMI_WDT=y
# CONFIG_ESP8266_XTAL_FREQ_40 is not set
CONFIG_ESP8266_XTAL_FREQ_26=y
CONFIG_ESP8266_XTAL_FREQ=26
# CONFIG_ESP8266_DEFAULT_CPU_FREQ_80 is not set
CONFIG_ESP8266_DEFAULT_CPU_FREQ_160=y
CONFIG_ESP8266_DEFAULT_CPU_FREQ_MHZ=160
CONFIG_ESP_FILENAME_MACRO_NO_PATH=y
# CONFIG_ESP_FILENAME_MACRO_RAW is not set
# CONFIG_ESP_FILENAME_MACRO_NULL is not set
CONFIG_USING_NEW_ETS_VPRINTF=y
# CONFIG_LINK_ETS_PRINTF_TO_IRAM is not set
CONFIG_ETS_PRINTF_EXIT_WHEN_FLASH_RW=y
# CONFIG_SOC_FULL_ICACHE is not set
CONFIG_SOC_IRAM_SIZE=0xC000
# CONFIG_DISABLE_ROM_UART_PRINT is not set
# CONFIG_ESP_PANIC_PRINT_HALT is not set
CONFIG_ESP_PANIC_PRINT_REBOOT=y
# CONFIG_ESP_PANIC_SILENT_REBOOT is not set
# CONFIG_ESP_PANIC_GDBSTUB is not set
CONFIG_RESET_REASON=y
CONFIG_WIFI_PPT_TASKSTACK_SIZE=5120
CONFIG_ESP8266_CORE_GLOBAL_DATA_LINK_IRAM=y
# CONFIG_ESP8266_OTA_FROM_OLD is not set
# CONFIG_ESP8266_BOOT_COPY_APP is not set
CONFIG_ESP8266_TIME_SYSCALL_USE_FRC1=y
# CONFIG_ESP8266_TIME_SYSCALL_USE_NONE is not set
# CONFIG_PM_ENABLE is not set
CONFIG_SCAN_AP_MAX=99
CONFIG_WIFI_TX_RATE_SEQUENCE_FROM_HIGH=y
# CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_QOS_ENABLED is not set
# CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_AMPDU_RX_ENABLED is not set
# CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_AMSDU_ENABLED is not set
CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_RX_BUFFER_NUM=16
CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_LEFT_CONTINUOUS_RX_BUFFER_NUM=16
CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_RX_PKT_NUM=7
CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_TX_PKT_NUM=6
CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_NVS_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_CONNECT_OPEN_ROUTER_WHEN_PWD_IS_SET=y
CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_ENABLE_WPA3_SAE=y
# CONFIG_ESP8266_WIFI_DEBUG_LOG_ENABLE is not set
CONFIG_ESP_PHY_CALIBRATION_AND_DATA_STORAGE=y
# CONFIG_ESP_PHY_INIT_DATA_IN_PARTITION is not set
CONFIG_ESP_PHY_INIT_DATA_VDD33_CONST=33
CONFIG_ESP8266_PHY_MAX_WIFI_TX_POWER=20
# CONFIG_ESP8266_HSPI_HIGH_THROUGHPUT is not set
CONFIG_ESP_ERR_TO_NAME_LOOKUP=y
CONFIG_ESP_SYSTEM_EVENT_QUEUE_SIZE=32
CONFIG_ESP_SYSTEM_EVENT_TASK_STACK_SIZE=2048
CONFIG_ESP_MAIN_TASK_STACK_SIZE=3584
CONFIG_ESP_TIMER_TASK_STACK_SIZE=3584
CONFIG_ESP_CONSOLE_UART_DEFAULT=y
# CONFIG_ESP_CONSOLE_UART_CUSTOM is not set
# CONFIG_ESP_CONSOLE_UART_NONE is not set
CONFIG_ESP_CONSOLE_UART_NUM=0
CONFIG_ESP_CONSOLE_UART_BAUDRATE=74880
# CONFIG_ESP_UART0_SWAP_IO is not set
CONFIG_ESP_TASK_WDT=y
CONFIG_ESP_TASK_WDT_PANIC=y
# CONFIG_ESP_TASK_WDT_TIMEOUT_13N is not set
# CONFIG_ESP_TASK_WDT_TIMEOUT_14N is not set
CONFIG_ESP_TASK_WDT_TIMEOUT_15N=y
CONFIG_ESP_TASK_WDT_TIMEOUT_S=15
# CONFIG_ESP_EVENT_LOOP_PROFILING is not set
CONFIG_ESP_EVENT_POST_FROM_ISR=y
CONFIG_ESP_HTTP_CLIENT_ENABLE_HTTPS=y
# CONFIG_ESP_HTTP_CLIENT_ENABLE_BASIC_AUTH is not set
CONFIG_HTTP_BUF_SIZE=512
CONFIG_HTTPD_MAX_REQ_HDR_LEN=512
CONFIG_HTTPD_MAX_URI_LEN=512
CONFIG_OTA_BUF_SIZE=256
# CONFIG_OTA_ALLOW_HTTP is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_DYNAMIC is not set
CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_437=y
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_720 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_737 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_771 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_775 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_850 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_852 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_855 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_857 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_860 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_861 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_862 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_863 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_864 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_865 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_866 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_869 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_932 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_936 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_949 is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE_950 is not set
CONFIG_FATFS_CODEPAGE=437
CONFIG_FATFS_LFN_NONE=y
# CONFIG_FATFS_LFN_HEAP is not set
# CONFIG_FATFS_LFN_STACK is not set
CONFIG_FATFS_FS_LOCK=0
CONFIG_FATFS_TIMEOUT_MS=10000
CONFIG_FATFS_PER_FILE_CACHE=y
CONFIG_FMB_COMM_MODE_TCP_EN=y
CONFIG_FMB_TCP_PORT_DEFAULT=502
CONFIG_FMB_TCP_PORT_MAX_CONN=5
CONFIG_FMB_TCP_CONNECTION_TOUT_SEC=20
CONFIG_FMB_MASTER_TIMEOUT_MS_RESPOND=150
CONFIG_FMB_MASTER_DELAY_MS_CONVERT=200
CONFIG_FMB_QUEUE_LENGTH=20
CONFIG_FMB_PORT_TASK_STACK_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_FMB_SERIAL_BUF_SIZE=256
CONFIG_FMB_PORT_TASK_PRIO=10
CONFIG_FMB_CONTROLLER_SLAVE_ID_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_FMB_CONTROLLER_SLAVE_ID=0x00112233
CONFIG_FMB_CONTROLLER_NOTIFY_TIMEOUT=20
CONFIG_FMB_CONTROLLER_NOTIFY_QUEUE_SIZE=20
CONFIG_FMB_CONTROLLER_STACK_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_FMB_EVENT_QUEUE_TIMEOUT=20
CONFIG_FMB_TIMER_GROUP=0
CONFIG_FMB_TIMER_INDEX=0
# CONFIG_FMB_TIMER_ISR_IN_IRAM is not set
# CONFIG_DISABLE_FREERTOS is not set
CONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE=y
# CONFIG_FREERTOS_ENABLE_REENT is not set
CONFIG_FREERTOS_NO_AFFINITY=0x7FFFFFFF
CONFIG_FREERTOS_HZ=100
CONFIG_FREERTOS_MAX_HOOK=2
CONFIG_FREERTOS_IDLE_TASK_STACKSIZE=1024
CONFIG_FREERTOS_ISR_STACKSIZE=512
# CONFIG_FREERTOS_EXTENED_HOOKS is not set
CONFIG_FREERTOS_GLOBAL_DATA_LINK_IRAM=y
# CONFIG_FREERTOS_CODE_LINK_TO_IRAM is not set
CONFIG_FREERTOS_TIMER_STACKSIZE=2048
CONFIG_TASK_SWITCH_FASTER=y
# CONFIG_USE_QUEUE_SETS is not set
# CONFIG_ENABLE_FREERTOS_SLEEP is not set
# CONFIG_FREERTOS_USE_TRACE_FACILITY is not set
# CONFIG_FREERTOS_GENERATE_RUN_TIME_STATS is not set
CONFIG_FREERTOS_WATCHPOINT_END_OF_STACK=y
# CONFIG_HEAP_DISABLE_IRAM is not set
# CONFIG_HEAP_TRACING is not set
CONFIG_LIBSODIUM_USE_MBEDTLS_SHA=y
# CONFIG_LOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL_NONE is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL_ERROR is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL_WARN is not set
CONFIG_LOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL_INFO=y
# CONFIG_LOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL_VERBOSE is not set
CONFIG_LOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL=3
CONFIG_LOG_COLORS=y
# CONFIG_LOG_SET_LEVEL is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_LOCAL_HOSTNAME="espressif"
CONFIG_LWIP_DNS_SUPPORT_MDNS_QUERIES=y
# CONFIG_LWIP_L2_TO_L3_COPY is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_IRAM_OPTIMIZATION is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_TIMERS_ONDEMAND=y
CONFIG_LWIP_MAX_SOCKETS=10
# CONFIG_LWIP_USE_ONLY_LWIP_SELECT is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_SO_LINGER is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_SO_REUSE=y
CONFIG_LWIP_SO_REUSE_RXTOALL=y
# CONFIG_LWIP_SO_RCVBUF is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_NETBUF_RECVINFO is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_IP4_FRAG=y
CONFIG_LWIP_IP6_FRAG=y
# CONFIG_LWIP_IP4_REASSEMBLY is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_IP6_REASSEMBLY is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_IP_FORWARD is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_STATS is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_ETHARP_TRUST_IP_MAC is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_ESP_GRATUITOUS_ARP=y
CONFIG_LWIP_GARP_TMR_INTERVAL=60
CONFIG_LWIP_TCPIP_RECVMBOX_SIZE=32
CONFIG_LWIP_DHCP_DOES_ARP_CHECK=y
# CONFIG_LWIP_DHCP_RESTORE_LAST_IP is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_DHCPS_LEASE_UNIT=60
CONFIG_LWIP_DHCPS_MAX_STATION_NUM=8
# CONFIG_LWIP_AUTOIP is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_IPV6_AUTOCONFIG is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_NETIF_LOOPBACK=y
CONFIG_LWIP_LOOPBACK_MAX_PBUFS=8
CONFIG_LWIP_MAX_ACTIVE_TCP=16
CONFIG_LWIP_MAX_LISTENING_TCP=16
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_MAXRTX=12
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_SYNMAXRTX=6
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_MSS=1440
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_TMR_INTERVAL=250
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_MSL=60000
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_SND_BUF_DEFAULT=2880
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_WND_DEFAULT=5760
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_RECVMBOX_SIZE=6
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_QUEUE_OOSEQ=y
# CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_SACK_OUT is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_KEEP_CONNECTION_WHEN_IP_CHANGES is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_OVERSIZE_MSS=y
# CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_OVERSIZE_QUARTER_MSS is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_OVERSIZE_DISABLE is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_TCP_RTO_TIME=3000
CONFIG_LWIP_MAX_UDP_PCBS=16
CONFIG_LWIP_UDP_RECVMBOX_SIZE=6
CONFIG_LWIP_TCPIP_TASK_STACK_SIZE=2048
CONFIG_LWIP_TCPIP_TASK_AFFINITY_NO_AFFINITY=y
# CONFIG_LWIP_TCPIP_TASK_AFFINITY_CPU0 is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_TCPIP_TASK_AFFINITY=0x7FFFFFFF
# CONFIG_LWIP_PPP_SUPPORT is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_IPV6_MEMP_NUM_ND6_QUEUE=3
CONFIG_LWIP_IPV6_ND6_NUM_NEIGHBORS=5
# CONFIG_LWIP_MULTICAST_PING is not set
# CONFIG_LWIP_BROADCAST_PING is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_MAX_RAW_PCBS=16
# CONFIG_LWIP_IPV6 is not set
CONFIG_LWIP_DHCP_MAX_NTP_SERVERS=1
CONFIG_LWIP_SNTP_UPDATE_DELAY=3600000
CONFIG_LWIP_ESP_LWIP_ASSERT=y
# CONFIG_LWIP_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_INTERNAL_MEM_ALLOC=y
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_DEFAULT_MEM_ALLOC is not set
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_CUSTOM_MEM_ALLOC is not set
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ASYMMETRIC_CONTENT_LEN=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_IN_CONTENT_LEN=16384
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_OUT_CONTENT_LEN=4096
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_DYNAMIC_BUFFER is not set
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_DEBUG=y
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_DEBUG_LEVEL_WARN is not set
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFO is not set
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_DEBUG_LEVEL_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_DEBUG_LEVEL_VERBOSE=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_DEBUG_LEVEL=4
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_HAVE_TIME=y
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_HAVE_TIME_DATE is not set
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_TLS_SERVER_AND_CLIENT=y
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_TLS_SERVER_ONLY is not set
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_TLS_CLIENT_ONLY is not set
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_TLS_DISABLED is not set
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_TLS_SERVER=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_TLS_CLIENT=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_TLS_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_PSK_MODES=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_PSK=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_DHE_PSK=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_ECDHE_PSK=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_RSA_PSK=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_RSA=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_DHE_RSA=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_ELLIPTIC_CURVE=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_ECDHE_RSA=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_ECDHE_ECDSA=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_ECDH_ECDSA=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_ECDH_RSA=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_RENEGOTIATION=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_SSL3=y
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_TLS1 is not set
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_TLS1_1 is not set
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_TLS1_2=y
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_GMTSSL1_1 is not set
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_DTLS is not set
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_ALPN=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_CLIENT_SSL_SESSION_TICKETS=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SERVER_SSL_SESSION_TICKETS=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_AES_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_CAMELLIA_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_DES_C=y
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_RC4_DISABLED is not set
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_RC4_ENABLED_NO_DEFAULT is not set
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_RC4_ENABLED=y
# CONFIG_MBEDTLS_BLOWFISH_C is not set
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_XTEA_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_CCM_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_GCM_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_RIPEMD160_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_PEM_PARSE_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_PEM_WRITE_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_X509_CRL_PARSE_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_X509_CSR_PARSE_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECDH_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECDSA_C=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP192R1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP224R1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP256R1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP384R1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP521R1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP192K1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP224K1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP256K1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_BP256R1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_BP384R1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_BP512R1_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_CURVE25519_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ECP_NIST_OPTIM=y
CONFIG_util_assert=y
CONFIG_ESP_SHA=y
CONFIG_ESP_AES=y
CONFIG_ESP_MD5=y
CONFIG_ESP_ARC4=y
# CONFIG_ENABLE_MDNS is not set
CONFIG_MQTT_PROTOCOL_311=y
CONFIG_MQTT_TRANSPORT_SSL=y
CONFIG_MQTT_TRANSPORT_WEBSOCKET=y
# CONFIG_MQTT_TRANSPORT_WEBSOCKET_SECURE is not set
# CONFIG_MQTT_USE_CUSTOM_CONFIG is not set
# CONFIG_MQTT_TASK_CORE_SELECTION_ENABLED is not set
# CONFIG_MQTT_CUSTOM_OUTBOX is not set
CONFIG_NEWLIB_STDOUT_LINE_ENDING_CRLF=y
# CONFIG_NEWLIB_STDOUT_LINE_ENDING_LF is not set
# CONFIG_NEWLIB_STDOUT_LINE_ENDING_CR is not set
CONFIG_NEWLIB_NANO_FORMAT=y
# CONFIG_OPENSSL_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_OPENSSL_ASSERT_DO_NOTHING=y
# CONFIG_OPENSSL_ASSERT_EXIT is not set
CONFIG_PTHREAD_TASK_PRIO_DEFAULT=5
CONFIG_PTHREAD_TASK_STACK_SIZE_DEFAULT=3072
CONFIG_PTHREAD_STACK_MIN=768
CONFIG_PTHREAD_TASK_NAME_DEFAULT="pthread"
# CONFIG_ENABLE_TH25Q16HB_PATCH_0 is not set
CONFIG_SPIFFS_MAX_PARTITIONS=3
CONFIG_SPIFFS_CACHE=y
CONFIG_SPIFFS_CACHE_WR=y
# CONFIG_SPIFFS_CACHE_STATS is not set
CONFIG_SPIFFS_PAGE_CHECK=y
CONFIG_SPIFFS_GC_MAX_RUNS=10
# CONFIG_SPIFFS_GC_STATS is not set
CONFIG_SPIFFS_PAGE_SIZE=256
CONFIG_SPIFFS_OBJ_NAME_LEN=32
CONFIG_SPIFFS_USE_MAGIC=y
CONFIG_SPIFFS_USE_MAGIC_LENGTH=y
CONFIG_SPIFFS_META_LENGTH=4
CONFIG_SPIFFS_USE_MTIME=y
# CONFIG_SPIFFS_DBG is not set
# CONFIG_SPIFFS_API_DBG is not set
# CONFIG_SPIFFS_GC_DBG is not set
# CONFIG_SPIFFS_CACHE_DBG is not set
# CONFIG_SPIFFS_CHECK_DBG is not set
# CONFIG_SPIFFS_TEST_VISUALISATION is not set
CONFIG_IP_LOST_TIMER_INTERVAL=120
CONFIG_TCPIP_ADAPTER_GLOBAL_DATA_LINK_IRAM=y
CONFIG_VFS_SUPPRESS_SELECT_DEBUG_OUTPUT=y
CONFIG_VFS_SUPPORT_TERMIOS=y
CONFIG_SEMIHOSTFS_MAX_MOUNT_POINTS=1
CONFIG_SEMIHOSTFS_HOST_PATH_MAX_LEN=128
# CONFIG_WL_SECTOR_SIZE_512 is not set
CONFIG_WL_SECTOR_SIZE_4096=y
CONFIG_WL_SECTOR_SIZE=4096
# CONFIG_ENABLE_UNIFIED_PROVISIONING is not set
CONFIG_LTM_FAST=y
CONFIG_WPA_MBEDTLS_CRYPTO=y
# CONFIG_WPA_DEBUG_PRINT is not set
# CONFIG_WPA_TESTING_OPTIONS is not set
# CONFIG_WPA_WPS_WARS is not set
# CONFIG_WPA_11KV_SUPPORT is not set

# Deprecated options for backward compatibility
CONFIG_TARGET_PLATFORM="esp8266"
CONFIG_TOOLPREFIX="xtensa-lx106-elf-"
# CONFIG_MAKE_WARN_UNDEFINED_VARIABLES is not set
# CONFIG_FLASHMODE_QIO is not set
# CONFIG_FLASHMODE_QOUT is not set
# CONFIG_FLASHMODE_DIO is not set
CONFIG_FLASHMODE_DOUT=y
# CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_9600B is not set
# CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_57600B is not set
CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_74880B=y
# CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_115200B is not set
# CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_230400B is not set
# CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_921600B is not set
# CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_2MB is not set
# CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_OTHER is not set
CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD_OTHER_VAL=74880
CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD=74880
CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL_DEBUG=y
# CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL_RELEASE is not set
CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_ASSERTIONS_ENABLED=y
# CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_ASSERTIONS_SILENT is not set
# CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_ASSERTIONS_DISABLED is not set
# CONFIG_CXX_EXCEPTIONS is not set
CONFIG_STACK_CHECK_NONE=y
# CONFIG_STACK_CHECK_NORM is not set
# CONFIG_STACK_CHECK_STRONG is not set
# CONFIG_STACK_CHECK_ALL is not set
# CONFIG_STACK_CHECK is not set
CONFIG_WARN_WRITE_STRINGS=y
CONFIG_MAIN_TASK_STACK_SIZE=3584
CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_DEFAULT=y
# CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_CUSTOM is not set
# CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_NONE is not set
CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_NUM=0
CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_BAUDRATE=74880
# CONFIG_UART0_SWAP_IO is not set
CONFIG_TASK_WDT=y
CONFIG_TASK_WDT_PANIC=y
CONFIG_TASK_WDT_TIMEOUT_S=15
CONFIG_MB_MASTER_TIMEOUT_MS_RESPOND=150
CONFIG_MB_MASTER_DELAY_MS_CONVERT=200
CONFIG_MB_QUEUE_LENGTH=20
CONFIG_MB_SERIAL_TASK_STACK_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_MB_SERIAL_BUF_SIZE=256
CONFIG_MB_SERIAL_TASK_PRIO=10
CONFIG_MB_CONTROLLER_SLAVE_ID_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_MB_CONTROLLER_SLAVE_ID=0x00112233
CONFIG_MB_CONTROLLER_NOTIFY_TIMEOUT=20
CONFIG_MB_CONTROLLER_NOTIFY_QUEUE_SIZE=20
CONFIG_MB_CONTROLLER_STACK_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_MB_EVENT_QUEUE_TIMEOUT=20
CONFIG_MB_TIMER_GROUP=0
CONFIG_MB_TIMER_INDEX=0
# CONFIG_L2_TO_L3_COPY is not set
# CONFIG_USE_ONLY_LWIP_SELECT is not set
CONFIG_ESP_GRATUITOUS_ARP=y
CONFIG_GARP_TMR_INTERVAL=60
CONFIG_TCPIP_RECVMBOX_SIZE=32
CONFIG_TCP_MAXRTX=12
CONFIG_TCP_SYNMAXRTX=6
CONFIG_TCP_MSS=1440
CONFIG_TCP_MSL=60000
CONFIG_TCP_SND_BUF_DEFAULT=2880
CONFIG_TCP_WND_DEFAULT=5760
CONFIG_TCP_RECVMBOX_SIZE=6
CONFIG_TCP_QUEUE_OOSEQ=y
# CONFIG_ESP_TCP_KEEP_CONNECTION_WHEN_IP_CHANGES is not set
CONFIG_TCP_OVERSIZE_MSS=y
# CONFIG_TCP_OVERSIZE_QUARTER_MSS is not set
# CONFIG_TCP_OVERSIZE_DISABLE is not set
CONFIG_UDP_RECVMBOX_SIZE=6
CONFIG_TCPIP_TASK_STACK_SIZE=2048
CONFIG_TCPIP_TASK_AFFINITY_NO_AFFINITY=y
# CONFIG_TCPIP_TASK_AFFINITY_CPU0 is not set
CONFIG_TCPIP_TASK_AFFINITY=0x7FFFFFFF
# CONFIG_PPP_SUPPORT is not set
CONFIG_ESP32_PTHREAD_TASK_PRIO_DEFAULT=5
CONFIG_ESP32_PTHREAD_TASK_STACK_SIZE_DEFAULT=3072
CONFIG_ESP32_PTHREAD_STACK_MIN=768
CONFIG_ESP32_PTHREAD_TASK_NAME_DEFAULT="pthread"
CONFIG_SUPPRESS_SELECT_DEBUG_OUTPUT=y
CONFIG_SUPPORT_TERMIOS=y
# End of deprecated options
```

How to debug the issue?

I've already tried to connect via mqtt clients and terminal with this certificates without any issue, but using Arduino or ESP-IDF on ESP8266 i'm not able to connect via certificates

Comment: Debug the issue by simplifying it. Open an unencrypted listener on the broker. Try to connect to that. If you can't then you have a basic connectivity issue that you need to solve. If you can then you know the device can actually reach the broker. Then turn on server side certificates and get that working. Then move on to client side certificates.

Comment: @romkey actually i am able to connect via credentials on the broker. as you can see the CA is validated. As wrote i am able to connect via mosquitto client and mqtt client via the client credentials signed by the CA but not able to connect via esp8266 (via Arduino and via ESP-IDF). I suppose is something related to cipher or some SSL version doesn't match between firmware and server